# How to wrap gulp scripts with jQuery document ready

Tags: gulp, coffeescript

I want to wrap `gulp` processed coffeescript with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`. This is because the projects implementation of jQuery uses the `jQuery` but the coffeescript files uses `$`.

Since it is an old project with a long history of quirks, I cannot change how jQuery are implemented. Also editing all JS files to use `jQuery` instead of `$` could potentially create problems in other areas of the codebase.

Relevant code in `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('components-scripts', function () {
    var components = getComponentGlobs('coffee');
    gulp.src(components)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(coffee().on('error', util.log))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.source + 'scripts'));
});
```

Will produce something like this in `script.js`:

```
(function() {
  // All processed coffee script code are here
}).call(this);
```

I want it to look like this:

```
(function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // All processed coffee script code are here
  });
}).call(this);
```

I use [gulp-coffee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-coffee) in `gulpfile.js`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [gulp-inject-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-string):

```
gulp.task('components-scripts', function () {
    var components = getComponentGlobs('coffee');
    gulp.src(components)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(coffee().on('error', util.log))
        .pipe(inject.after('(function() {', '\njQuery(document).ready(function ($) {\n'))
        .pipe(inject.before('}).call(this);', '});\n'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.source + 'scripts'));
});
```